# Animate image from center to bottom on splashscreen

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

W10 Mobile offers to make extended splashscreen. I use Template10 and their guideline to make extended splashscreen. I have 3 images of sizes: `620x300`, `1240x600`, `2480x1200px`. Extended splashscreen is working fine, but I'would like to animate the image from center to bottom. Here is the code of setting up the image:

```
SplashScreenImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, SplashScreen.ImageLocation.X);
        SplashScreenImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Y);

        if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
        {
            SplashScreenImage.Height = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Height / ScaleFactor;
            SplashScreenImage.Width = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Width / ScaleFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            SplashScreenImage.Height = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Height;
            SplashScreenImage.Width = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Width;
        }
```

Height is 731 effective pixels and Width is 411 effective pixels. But the image is center, and I would like to get the sizes of centered image. I'm not sure, what Windows does and if it scales the image.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you actually want to do. Do you want to get the sizes of the centered image or you want to location the image to bottom?Or you want a animation as splash screen? If I don't understand you clearly please kindly tell me.

Comment: I want to animate the image on extended splash screen

Comment: So when the app load the extended splash screen,the image can transfer from center to bottom? Do it one time? You have three images, do you need to animate between the three images?

Comment: Yes. When extended splashscreen is loaded I start to animate the image from center to bottom and after animation is completed, navigate to login screen.

Answer (score 1):

> When extended splashscreen is loaded I start to animate the image from center to bottom

You can use [story animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx) to do this. For example, here I use `DoubleAnimationUingKeyFrames`, you can choose the adapt animation you want.

Xaml Code

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="storyboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SplashScreenImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="50" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="120" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:9" Value="400" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Image x:Name="SplashScreenImage"
               Loaded="SplashImage_Loaded"
               Source="Assets/foo600320.jpg">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>              
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind, add `storyboard.Begin();` to your code.

```
  SplashScreenImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Y);
  if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
  {
      SplashScreenImage.Height = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Height / ScaleFactor;
      SplashScreenImage.Width = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Width / ScaleFactor;
  }
  else
  {
      SplashScreenImage.Height = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Height;
      SplashScreenImage.Width = SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Width;
  }
  storyboard.Begin();
```

This animation will let your image from center to bottom in nine seconds.

> after animation is completed, navigate to login screen.

For this you can use the [Completed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) to navigate to the login screen.Like

```
storyboard.Completed += MyStoryboard_Completed;
private void MyStoryboard_Completed(object sender, object e)
{
    // Navigate to mainpage
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    // Place the frame in the current Window
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
}
```

I have a complete [demo](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/CSplashScreen) uploaded you can reference.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not what I want. I need to animate image and stop it on bottom. So I need to know the size of image

Comment: @JuP Are you still work on this?  Of course you know the size of image, by this code `SplashScreenImage.Height `. You set the height and width for the splashscreenimage, and of course you can get them.

Comment: I know, I can use this. But from Height property I get value 1280, but the image is not on whole screen, but it is centered and scaled, so the real size is not 1280

Comment: @JuP  to meet your requirements, not only to know the image size also the window size. I set the `ApplicationView`to 800*800, and the `canvas.top` for image is 250, the height of the image is 300, and at last set the animation `TranslateTransform.Y` to (800-250-300=250), and it works. You should control all the sizes.I have updated the [demo](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/blob/master/CSplashScreen/CSplashScreen/ExtendedSplash.xaml.cs).The height is just what you set, it should not have anything wrong.If my answer helped you ,could you please mark as answer?

Comment: why did you set canvas.top on 250?

Comment: @Jup this is my top, this can let the image center. And yours in this code `SplashScreenImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, SplashScreen.ImageLocation.Y);` You set the `canvas.top` here, and you can get the value to calculate.

Comment: But when I do this, top value is 0. I dont know why